# is there are any functional way to filter a person's name in PHP

Tags: php, string, filtering

Like if someone submits "Jame c+@risti" (not an actual name) it will return false.
There are so many symbolic characters there which will take ages to filter manually.
I also want to pass Latin, Chinese, Bengali etc continental language characters... but want to reject which are illegal for a name (eg: +↙▶ⓚ!♥ etc.)

Comment: Yes, there must be a way. What have you tried so far?

Comment: I just filtered ascii symbols and numbers but cannot outside ascii

Comment: who says ♥ is a illegal name character?

Comment: I don't think anyone has registered his/her name containing ♥ in his/her birth certificate in this world..... (-_-)

Comment: @AritraHazra but so many would wish to :)

Comment: Well I'll let them use those in an optional username but I don't want it in real name right now.... ;) if naming style changes in real world then I'll change it for sure

Comment: http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: I would suggest regexes

Answer (score 0):

Deciding what are and are not valid names is incredibly hard.

The long if it is detailed in [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

The short of it is you could simply scan for illegal characters. E.g.

```
<?php
function isValidName($name) {
  $illegals = array("+", "↙", "▶", "ⓚ", "!", "♥");
  foreach ($illegals as $illegal) {
    if (strpos($name, $illegal)) { return false; }
  }
  return true;
}
```

This is incredibly inefficient and you should much rather allow most anything as names. Especially considering you wish to accept Chinese and other non-ascii characters in names. PHP has notoriously bad multibyte rune support so this is another problem in itself.